# Python Fastapi. No headers after redirect

Tags: fastapi

I'm doing a test via "test_client" and testing the `"/me"` endpoint which redirects, depending on the incoming token, to the secure endpoint either `/users/user_id` or `/operators/operator_id`. But after redirection headers become None`.
If I doing it via swagger - all works correctly, if I doing this via curl - I'm don't getting an answer at all.
So, the main problem is that headers are becoming are empty (no token) after redirection.

There is my code:

```
@app.api_route(path="/me",
               status_code=308,
               methods=["GET", "DELETE", "PATCH"],
               tags=['me'],)
def get_my_profile(request: fastapi.Request, token: str = fastapi.Depends(config.oauth2_scheme), ):
    token_payload = services_get_token_payload(token=token)
    if token_payload['role'] == config.USER_ROLE:
        url = f"{request.url.scheme}://{config.APP_IP}:{config.APP_PORT}/users/{token_payload['sub']}"
    elif token_payload['role'] == config.OPERATOR_ROLE:
        url = f"{request.url.scheme}://{config.APP_IP}:{config.APP_PORT}/operators/{token_payload['sub']}"
    elif token_payload['role'] == config.EMPLOYEE_ROLE:
        url = f"{request.url.scheme}://{config.APP_IP}:{config.APP_PORT}/employees/{token_payload['sub']}"
    else:
        raise fastapi.HTTPException('Can not redirect, some error occurred')
    return fastapi.responses.RedirectResponse(url=url, status_code=308, headers=request.headers)  # No matter `request.headers` or `dict(request.headers)`
    

@router.get(path="/{user_id}", status_code=200, response_model=schemas.UserOut)
async def get_user(
        user_id: int = Path(default=...),
        token: str = Depends(config.oauth2_scheme),  # error during checking, no headers
        postgres_session: AsyncSession = Depends(database.get_db),):
    token_payload = services.get_token_payload(token=token)
    services.verify_access(role=token_payload["role"], true_conds=token_payload['sub'] == user_id)
    user = await crud.read_user(statement=users.select().where(users.c.id == user_id), db_session=postgres_session)
    return schemas.UserOut(**user)
```

Proof with curl:

```
david@david-ThinkPad-E480:~$ curl -X 'GET' \
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8000/me' \
>   -H 'accept: */*' \
>   -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.c66ACoJpTLRXYMeysEYwUIQJSqIMEXegXRn4vc0sIMw'
david@david-ThinkPad-E480:~$
```

Comment: Headers are not resent after a redirect by default; it would be the responsibility of the client you're using to do that. (Just like POST or other data isn't re-sent after a redirect by default). You'd usually configure your client to include the authorization header globally for any instance.

Comment: @MatsLindh are there any headers that will tell to the client that the same headers required?

Comment: No, 308 is probably the closest you'll come. `curl` requires the `-L` flag to follow redirects; not sure if that will also make it resend the headers you gave it. You might also want to add `-i` to show the headers given from the server properly. In your frontend it'll depend on how you're making requests to the backend; for example axios can be configured with headers set on the client level itself, which will then be used for any request.